# How to execute a line of CoffeScript if a variable exists?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

I want to send the second line of the next code to the client only if eliminate member variable is true.

```
<% if @eliminate %>
$("div#asset-details").html("<%=escape_javascript(render partial: 'assets/landing_for_asset')%>")
<% end %>
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Forgive me if I am wrong, but it seems that the code block you have would do that?

Comment: Do you get an error when executing? The line Seems ok